# Having troubles executing HP ALM test suite remotely

Tags: c#, api, ota, hp-quality-center

I am attempting to invoke a test suite in ALM programmatically. I have no issue running the specified test suite on my local machine when I execute the code (when my machine acts as a test runner). I run into an issue however when I attempt to point to a remote server to run said test suite. Code and error message posted here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TDAPIOLELib;


        // Connect to ALM
        ITDConnection itdc = new TDConnection();
        itdc.InitConnectionEx(url);
        itdc.ConnectProjectEx(domain, projectName, username, pswd);

        if (itdc.ProjectConnected)
        {
            List<string> testInfo = new List<string>();

            string testFolder = "Root\\<Folder>\\<Folder>";
            testSetName = "<TestSuite>";

            TestSetFactory tsFactory = (TestSetFactory)itdc.TestSetFactory;
            TestSetTreeManager tsTreeMgr = (TestSetTreeManager)itdc.TestSetTreeManager;

            TestSetFolder tsFolder = (TestSetFolder)tsTreeMgr.get_NodeByPath(testFolder);
            List tList = tsFolder.FindTestSets(testSetName, false, null);
            TestSet testset = tList[1];

            TSScheduler scheduler = testset.StartExecution("<RemoteServerName>"); // Contain server name unless local
            // scheduler.RunAllLocally = true; // Included when ran local
            scheduler.Run();                
        }
```

The error message I recieve at the 'scheduler' declaration line is "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))".

I have registered the OTAClient.dll on both my local machine and the machine that I have attempted to execute on.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

- Next steps

  - Call a young and old priest.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the issue was. It would be nice if there was more documentation available on this library.

You need to set a few TSScheduler properties before the execution can commence. So this line:

```
TSScheduler scheduler = testset.StartExecution("<RemoteServerName>"); // Contain server name unless local
// scheduler.RunAllLocally = true; // Included when ran local
scheduler.Run();
```

Became this:

```
TSScheduler scheduler = testset.StartExecution(""); // Contain server name unless local
scheduler.TdHostName = "<test_runner_name>";
scheduler.LogEnabled = true;
scheduler.Run(testset.ID);
```

Also would be a good idea if you confirm that you have all of the necessary ALM add-ins installed on your machine. Specifically the "HP Quality Center Connectivity" and "HP Quality Center System Test Remote Agent" add-ins. I re-installed on my test agents just to be sure.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I was already using

`TSScheduler scheduler = testSet.StartExecution("");`

We had a working solution in QC10, but recently upgraded to QC12. Installing the connectivity located at

> [yourALMURL.com/qcbin/TDConnectivity_index.html](https://yourALMURL.com/qcbin/TDConnectivity_index.html)

allowed us to use the COM object in VS2013 / C#, connect to QC etc but would fail with the same error you had on the code above.

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Eventually we found that you also need to 'register your client' by going to tools/client registration:

> https://yourALMURL.com/qcbin/CommonMode_index.html

Running IE as admin, and installing the components on that page.

I hope this helps someone :)